# Ng map marker icon with params (url to hosted image) not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, ng-map

In ng map this works:

```
<marker ng-repeat="helper in helpers" position="{{helper.position}}" optimized="false" icon={{helper.facebook.freshURL}}"></marker>
```

But if I put in params in "icon":

```
<marker ng-repeat="helper in helpers" position="{{helper.position}}" optimized="false" icon="{url: '{{helper.facebook.freshURL}}', anchor: [0,0]}"></marker>
```

It seems that the url has a prefix with "localhost:8000" before the url, and I get an error:

```
GET http://localhost:8100/%7Burl:%20https://graph.facebook.com/1716361775351742/picture?type=normal,%20anchor:%20[0,0]} 404 (Not Found)
```

Is this a bug or some syntax error on my side? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is related with the JSON error that occurs while parsing the expression: `{url: '{{helper.facebook.freshURL}}', anchor: [0,0]}`

Once the *valid* expression is provided for `icon` attribute, for example `icon='{"url":"{{helper.facebook.freshURL}}","anchor":[0,0]}'`, the marker icon will be properly initialized.

Example

```js
var app = angular.module('appMaps', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('mapCtrl', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.cities = [
       { id: 1, name : "Brisbane", location: [-33.867396, 151.206854] }
    ];


    $scope.iconProperties = {
       url : "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png",
       anchor: [0,0]   
    };

    $scope.iconUrl = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png";

});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appMaps" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
        <map center="[-24.667856, 133.630694]" zoom="3">
            <!--marker id='ID{{city.id}}' ng-repeat="city in cities" position="{{city.location}}" icon="{{iconProperties}}" -->
            <marker id='ID{{city.id}}' ng-repeat="city in cities" position="{{city.location}}" icon='{"url":"{{iconUrl}}","anchor":[0,0]}'>
            </marker>
            
        </map>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim, rookie mistake. However, now I get the error: "InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and no url property; and no path property". Do you have any clue what causes this?

Comment: Or if I use "custom-marker" I get the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null", and the marker won't render. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possibly a bug. Was trying to find the documentation so far, but couldn't. Possibly a RegEx issue

If still looking, remove the protocol and then try it. So your url looks like this.

```
helper.facebook.freshURL = '//graph.facebook.com/1716361775351742/picture?type=normal';
```

Let us know.